# Sort and Pagination

Tags: php, ajax

Please help im working on a search or filter i have records in my database my search is working.
There are 2 things that currently do not function accordingly:

1. When clicking the pagination link after a specific search (location; business unit; date submitted), the results change to include all vacancies in the database and does not maintain the search criteria.
2. The sorting of the view of vacancies also does not maintain the search criteria.

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant pieces of code.

Comment: The problem is on line 10, there's a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are missing to pass search criteria when sorting/pagination request is executed. PHP is stateles. It does not "remember" what has happened during previous request and you must use session to remember search criteria and aplly them on each request when it is needed or pass it with each request from client (that may be parameters in link like `search.php?location=searched_location&business=business_criteria` or, in your case, you must pass criteria with ajax request when page is changed or sort order is changed)